# How to keep xml from converting /r/n into &#xD;&#xA;

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word

I have here a small code:

```
string attributeValue = "Hello" + Environment.NewLine + " Hello 2";

XElement element = new XElement("test");
XElement subElement = new XElement("subTest");
XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute("key", "Hello");
XAttribute attribute2 = new XAttribute("key2", attributeValue);
subElement.Add(attribute);
subElement.Add(attribute2);
element.Add(subElement);

Console.Write(element.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

I have an issue, basically the /r/n or the new line is converted in `&#xD;&#xA;` in attribute, but I dont want to have it, I want to keep it /r/n as when I use this XML with the Microsoft Word documents template, the new lines are not implemented, although it is multilined text, in word document I only get the spaces. But no new lines :/

Anyone has any idea?

Although i've set the allow multi line int he property of the field in the template.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually the behaviour you get with `&#xD;&#xA;` is the same than the one of `Environment.NewLine`. You can do a simple test to confirm this (add two `TextBoxes` to your `Form` with the `Multiline property` set to `True`: `textBox1` and `textBox2`):

```
textBox1.Text = element.ToString(); //&#xD;&#xA;
string text = element.ToString().Replace("&#xD;&#xA;", Environment.NewLine);
textBox2.Text = text; ///r/n
```

On the other hand, if you want to avoid the `&#xD;&#xA;` part anyway (for example: because of wanting to output the given string to an external program not working on .NET), you can just rely on the aforementioned `Replace` after dealing with `XElement` and new lines.